# Install Pandoc inside Azure Function for Pypandoc

Tags: python, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, pandoc, pypandoc

I am using the package [pypandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/) for converting DOC/DOCX files into HTML. This has a prerequisite of Pandoc being already installed. When both packages are installed using the `requirements.txt` file, it works locally. When I deploy it as an Azure Function, however, it always gives a "module not found" error. (pypandoc cannot find pandoc in the same path because it gets installed elsewhere.)

This seems like a known issue. Pandoc does not get installed in the same path as Pyandoc and there are multiple solutions suggested. But they only locally.

Options tried:

1. Use [pandoc_download](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/)

   ```
     from pypandoc.pandoc_download import download_pandoc
   ```
2. [Use wdc](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/issues/324). This does not fix the problem.
3. [Use wheel files](https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc/issues/173) that include Pandoc.

Right now I am using mammoth for conversion which is slightly lower in accuracy, but gets deployed on Az. How can I get Pypandoc working as an Azure Function? How can I install Pandoc in a place where Pypandoc can find it? Or, how can I tell Pypandoc where to find Pandoc?

Comment: if azure functions support arbitrary docker images, see https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles

Answer (score 1):

I test it in my side, I install `pandoc` and `pypandoc` in local by the command `pip install pypandoc` and `pip install pandoc` but not install them using `requirements.txt`. The function works fine in local.

And then I generate the `requirements.txt` by running the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Then deploy the function to azure by running the command `func azure functionapp publish <your function app name> --build remote`, azure will install the modules according the content of `requirements.txt`. After the deployment, the function run success on azure portal.